# How do I Reorder Recent Items[Applications] in Start Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, start-menu, ordering

I am using the "recent items" feature of the Start Menu in Win7, but the only problem is the most used items are closer to the top, while the least used are at the bottom.

I think it would be more ideal to have the most used items near the bottom, since usually you open this menu by clicking the start button, which is at the bottom.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Move your taskbar to the top of the screen :) Seriously though I don't know the answer

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunatly no way to change the recent item display order.

You can pin items to your taskbar, when clicking on the item it will open the most recent for that particular application.

There is a detailed article on this with screenshot at How-To Geek [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3218/how-to-drag-files-to-the-taskbar-to-open-them-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Whilst good, Pinned items go to the top and the question is about him wanting his most used items at the bottom!

Comment: @Wil - Agreed. However this is an alternative and speeds up the process since the list order cannot be changed.

Comment: Your right, thinking of your answer in more detail, he could possibly set items displayed on the taskbar to 0, pin any item he wants then reorder the pinned items :S... Going to submit this as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible through any user set-able option.

As someone said in their comment, the easiest way would simply be to move the taskbar to the top of the screen, but this is more of a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking your question over and with what Diago says in mind, it would be possible for you to achieve what you want by right clicking the start orb and going to properties,  then clicking customise, and turn "number of recent programs to display" from whatever it is set as to 0.

Then you can just pin any items you want to the taskbar in reverse order as the oldest you pin will appear at the top.

I do not think that there is anyway to sort this list (backward step? I could do that in Windows 98?) as I just tried but it kept trying to open programs with other programs, but I could be wrong here, and I am sure there must be a list somewhere in the registry or directory that has the order... I will try to hunt it down later unless someone else knows?

Answer (score 0):

Those are sorted by date descending. Short of changing the date of the files on disk, it's not possible.

Comment: Eh?  This cant be right, I think you are thinking of the recent documents, not the recent apps, which are sorted by most used to least used, top to bottom.